# Test vectors for TLS PRF function

Tags: tls, test-vectors

Does anyone know where I might be able to find test vectors for the PRF function in TLS? (either 1.0 or newer). I'm trying to implement a client and I am getting the BAD Record MAC return after sending my encrypted client finished message. I'm pretty sure everything seems to be working so I'm kinda scratching my head wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Google finds some for TLS 1.2: https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/tls/current/msg03416.html